# Deep Linking with Facebook, Twitter, Etc

Tags: deep-linking

I have a website that has links to pages on various social networks (specifically, Twitter, Facebook, YouTube, and Instagram). All I want to do is make it so that when a user is on our site on a mobile phone and they have the corresponding app, the page will open up within the corresponding app when they click a link. So, if they have the Facebook app and click on the Facebook page link, the Facebook app will open. Obviously, I'll need fallbacks if they don't have the app or are on desktop.

I've seen different services that do deep linking but I can't find info on deep linking to, for instance, a Facebook business page. Does anyone know of a service that helps with this?

Comment: I don't think that is the tag you are looking for... (looking for proper term now)

Comment: Thanks! Maybe that's part of my problem!

Comment: It looks like that *is* the proper term, but the tag "description" is completely wrong. I'll open a Meta question about that. This might help you as well: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/app-installs-and-deep-linking . It appears that each app can be different and requires different meta data. : /